# Can't add variable to directory in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and am trying to add a folder name to a directory and can't get it to work. If anyone can provide some guidance that would be greatly appreciated.

```
$Folder = Set-Location 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assets\uploads\duplicating'
Write-Output $Folder
```

I tried both  this:

```
$Folder2 = $Folder + $ArrYear
```

and this

```
$Folder2 = Set-Location 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assets\uploads\duplicating\$ArrYear'
Write-Output $Folder2 




$Folder = Set-Location 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assets\uploads\duplicating'
  Write-Host $Folder


$ArrYear = Get-ChildItem 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assets\uploads\duplicating' |
       Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
$ChildY = $ArrYear
#Write-Output $ArrYear 
 Foreach ($ArrYear in $ChildY){


 If ($ArrYear -lt $YearInt){
    #$Folder2 = $Folder + $ArrYear
    $Folder2 = Set-Location 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assets\uploads\duplicating\$ArrYear'
    Write-Output $Folder
    Write-Output $Folder2
 }
  ElseIf($ArrYear -eq $YearInt){ 
    #$Folder2 = $Folder + $ArrYear
    $Folder2 = Set-Location 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assets\uploads\duplicating\$ArrYear'
    Write-Output $Folder
    Write-Output $Folder2
 }
 }
```

Comment: Just change the single quotes in this `'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\assets\uploads\duplicating\$ArrYear'` to double quotes and you should be set. The single quotes do not allow variable substitution.

Comment: However, the variable `$Folder2` would be empty because the cmdlet `Set-Location` doesn't return anything. All it does is change the directory to the one you pass it to. `$Folder2 = (Get-Location).path` right after the `Set-Location` line would give a better result.

Comment: as `Sid` pointed out, `Set-Location` does not return anything. once you fix that, then i recommend you use the `Join-Path` cmdlet to build your paths instead of doing it manually.

Comment: `Set-Location ... -PassThru` is also an option :)

Comment: Thanks Everyone. I went with the $Folder2 = (Get-Location).path. It works great.